# Distribution of $\langle A,x\rangle\langle A,y\rangle + \langle B,x\rangle\langle B,y\rangle$ given $\langle x, y\rangle$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, inner-products

Let $A$ and $B$ be independent, normal distributed $N(0,1)$ normalized unit vectors,
and let $x$ and $y$ be unit vectors with given inner product $\langle x, y\rangle=u$.

Can we write the distribution of $$\langle A,x\rangle\langle A,y\rangle + \langle B,x\rangle\langle B,y\rangle$$ as a function of $u$?

That is, if we randomly project two points onto normal distributed (unit) vectors, I wonder how the inner product is distributed? We know that for non-normalized $A$ and $B$ the distance is nicely distributed after projection (per 2-stability), but I can't seem to find strong arguments for or against a similar property holding for inner products.

Comment: It seems that you are looking for a inner-product preservation projection similar to the JL lemma.

Comment: That would be nice, but I don't think it exists. Instead I'm just looking for what guarantees we can get with normal distributions and going to two dimensions.

Comment: I agree. I also conjecture that the distribution you ask for can't be a function of $u$ alone. Anyway, I've voted up to see whether anyone else can clarify it.

Comment: Intuitively I feel like the fact that the vectors are unit vectors, and the random rotation property of the Gaussians should be enough, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Also, it works in expectation, where you get $n\sqrt{2/\pi}\langle x,y\rangle$, $n$ being the number of dimensions you reduce to. Maybe I can just use an AMS sketch then.

Comment: Wow. Sounds good! Could you provide a detailed proof  for that, i.e., the expectation?

Comment: Basically if you expand the expression you get the grand sum of $(AA^T+BB^T)\odot xy^T$. If the elements of $A$ and $B$ are zero in expectation, so are all the non diagonal elements of $AA^T$ and $BB^T$, but not the diagonals. Hence only the diagonal of $xy^T$ survives, which is $\langle x,y\rangle$.

Comment: I will try it later. :)